# Keyboard stopped responding on my Windows VM's hosted by OSX

Tags: keyboard, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion, parallels, osx-el-capitan

I am having an issue with all of my Windows virtual machines running on top of OSX El-Capitan version 10.11.3.
Hardware is MacBook Pro 15" Mid 2015.

The issue is that my keyboard input stopped responding and I'm having a "blip" sound whenever I striking a key, any key.
It's effects Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 on Parallels 11 or VMWare fusion 8.1.

The keyboard does work properly when I use my Mac or even more strange when I enter my credentials to login into my VMs.

I did try:

1. Rebooting Host
2. Reboot VM's,
3. Shutdown VM's and turn them on again.
4. Install the Tools (VMware on Fusion, Parallel on the Parallels VMs)
5. Connecting external keyboard

The mouse, is working well.

I'm frustrated by that issue.
Any ideas of how to solve that?

Everything is updated to the last update, including the Mac.
One Windows 10 VM is the latest release, the other is the latest DP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't know why, but I had an idea to access the ease of access menu in the settings.

Saw something that called "filter keys".
Disabled it (on each of my VMs), and now it's working.
I have no idea why it happened on all of them the same time, but that fixed the issue.